# Intersection of multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a number of dataframes (100) in a list as:

```
frameList = [df1,df2,..,df100]
```

Each dataframe has the two columns `DateTime`, `Temperature`.

I want to intersect all the dataframes on the common `DateTime` column and get all their  `Temperature` columns combined/merged into one big dataframe: Temperature from df1, Temperature from df2, Temperature from df3, .., Temperature from df100.

(pandas `merge` doesn't work as I'd have to compute multiple (99) pairwise intersections).

Comment: (I tried to reword to be simpler and clearer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`, which works on a list of DataFrames or Series.

```
pd.concat(frameList, axis=1, join='inner')
```

This is better than using `pd.merge`, as `pd.merge` will copy the data pairwise every time it is executed. `pd.concat` copies only once. However, `pd.concat` only merges based on an axes, whereas `pd.merge` can also merge on (multiple) columns.

Comment: It keeps multiplie "DateTime" columns after concat. Is there a way to keep only 1 "DateTime".

Comment: yes, make the DateTime the index, for each dataframe: `[df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True) for df in frameList]`.

Answer (score 5):

you can try using reduce functionality in python..something like this

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, dfN]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='DateTime'), dfs)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works through reduce?

Comment: inner function lambda just merges two dataframe at a given time.....`reduce` takes a function and a  `list` to work on....it takes two element from the list at a time works on it....the following explains in details  http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php.....hope you accept and upvote my answer....

Comment: I think my question was not clear. So, I am getting all the temperature columns merged into one column. I still want to keep them separate as I explained in the edit to my question.

Comment: this will keep temperature column from each dataframe ...the result will be like this "DateTime" | Temperatue_1 | Temperature_2 ....| Temperature_n.....is that wat you wanted

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over your list like this:

```
df_merge = frameList[0]
for df in frameList[1:]:       
    df_merge = pd.merge(df_merge, df, on='DateTime', how='inner')
```