# How to find the intersection of multiple pandas dataframes on a non index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found an answer that works for me to this Q and will post as well.

How to take a list of dataframes and create a new df that has only the rows that share a common value in a non index column?

Basically an intersection, but concat and merge wouldn't work for me for a number of reasons.

**I looked at the following and didn't get what i needed:**

[Finding common rows (intersection) in two Pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618912/finding-common-rows-intersection-in-two-pandas-dataframes)

[Pandas merge df error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008957/pandas-merge-df-error)

[How to get intersection of dataframes based on column labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876874/how-to-get-intersection-of-dataframes-based-on-column-labels)

[Intersection of multiple pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533467/intersection-of-multiple-pandas-dataframes)

[How to find intersection of dataframes based on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221755/how-to-find-intersection-of-dataframes-based-on-multiple-columns)

[Intersection of pandas dataframe with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539010/intersection-of-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-columns)

[How to do intersection of dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680259/how-to-do-intersection-of-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: This would do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26921975/11610186

Comment: merge can be made to work but only does 2 dfs, so for list of dfs a loop is still needed. the loop below avoids generating pairwise combinatorics and iteratively reducing.

Comment: Ah, this one I would keep, as per your answer. I would just change the intersection of 2 - the link I shared has better option for this bit, than what you proposed (i.e. the ```loc``` thing)

Comment: the problem with merge is that is mangles the index values and the column headings. I will list the problem with merge in the answer.

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski If you agree with the Q and/or the A can you please upvote one or both?

Comment: No, sorry- I don't. Still doing ```pd.merge(df1, df2[col], on=col,...)``` would be better. In your solution you literally return whole ```Series``` and check every single row of other dataframe against every row of this returned one (it's ```O(n^2)```). There's no way really you can't make any form of ```join``` work for you instead.

Comment: So how would you keep the index and column heads in tact?

Comment: Also, from this page it seems that loc does not go row by row but works on the entire set at once. Why do you think otherwise?https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up implementing. Would like to see if anyone has other ways of doing this more efficiently.

```
import copy

dfs_array = [ df1, df2, df3, df4, ... ]

def intersection_of_dfs(dfs_array,col='Ticker'):
    if len(dfs_array) <= 1:
        # if we only have 1 or 0 elements simply return the origial array
        # no error is given, logic must be created for the return value.
        return dfs_array
    # does a shallow copy only.
    dfs = copy.copy(dfs_array)
    length = len(dfs) 
    while length > 1:
        df1 = dfs.pop()
        df2 = dfs.pop()
        df0 = df1.loc[ df1[col].isin( df2[col].values ) ]
        dfs.insert(0,df0)
        length = len(dfs)
    return dfs
```

The suggestion to use merge wont work because it mangles the index and the column heads.

This is what merge gives:

```
>     [   open_x_x  high_x_x  low_x_x  close_x_x  volume_x_x Ticker  ...  LowAboveShort_y_y  ShortAboveLong_y_y  Return_y_y  DayDiff_y_y 
> AboveBelow_y_y  ShortToLong_y_y
>     0     52.60     52.68    52.24    52.4779        7632   AADR  ...            0.28214            1.087176    0.043298     2.600000             2.0         8.000000
>     1     14.03     14.03    14.03    14.0300         359   AAMC  ...            0.17472            0.628733    0.202228     1.333333             7.0         2.600000
>     2      2.15      2.15     1.72     1.9500       10095   AAME  ...           -0.20068            0.107564    0.114286     1.000000             1.0         0.636364
>     
>     [3 rows x 61 columns]]
```

And this is what the code below gives:

```
>     [             open   high    low    close  volume Ticker  Difference     LongMA   ShortMA  HighBelowShort  LowAboveShort 
> ShortAboveLong    Return   DayDiff  AboveBelow  ShortToLong
>     timestamp                                                                                                                                                                           
>     2019-12-12  52.60  52.68  52.24  52.4779    7632   AADR      0.1379  50.870684  51.95786         0.72214        0.28214        1.087176  0.043298  2.600000         2.0     8.000000
>     2019-12-12  14.03  14.03  14.03  14.0300     359   AAMC     -0.0100  13.226547  13.85528         0.17472        0.17472        0.628733  0.202228  1.333333         7.0     2.600000
>     2019-12-12   2.15   2.15   1.72   1.9500   10095   AAME      0.1900   1.813116   1.92068         0.22932       -0.20068        0.107564  0.114286  1.000000         1.0     0.636364]
```

Notice how the timestamp is maintained as are the column headings.

Comment: With no other ideas I am accepting my answer. Using merge alters the headings and to merge thousands of dataframes creates completely unrecognizable headers. Also, I couldn't figure out how to use merge to keep the column index intact without recreating the entire df. Using my method on a list of dfs of ~250kb takes only a few microseconds longer per df which is an acceptable level of compute cost for the solution.